Need to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 via Powershell
I have to install the below Visual C++ software via powershell.

VC_redist_2015-2022x64
VC_redist_2015-2022x86

I have to first check whether the Visual C++ x64 & x86 installed on my server. If its installed already code have to skip the installation part or else it have to install the Visual C++ x64 & x84. I have a powershell code which is not working properly. I am trying to short via name. But my code is not working.
Could someone please help me to fix it
I am looking forward to hearing from you.
$MSRedistributable = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Product where name = 'Microsoft Visual C++'"
$MSRedistributableInstaller = "C:\Software"

Write-host "`nStaring Installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022"
if (!($MSRedistributable.name))
{
Write-host "Installing Microsoft Visual C++."
Start-Process -Filepath "$($MSRedistributableInstaller)\VC_redist_2015-2022x64" -Argumentlist "/Q" -wait
Start-Process -Filepath "$($MSRedistributableInstaller)\VC_redist_2015-2022x86" -Argumentlist "/Q" -wait
write-host "Microsoft Visual C++ installed successfully."
}
else
{
write-host "$($MSRedistributable.name) appears to be installed already.  Skipping."
}


"...my code is not working." What happens when you run this code? Copy and paste any error messages into the question as text. No pictures. Read about how to ask questions on SO under https://stackoverflow.com/help.

I have a guess about your question. In your code, on line 1, the query statement should be modified from = to like, similar to the example:
(base) PS C:\Users\tzcbz> Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Product where name = 'Microsoft Visual C++'"

(base) PS C:\Users\tzcbz> Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Product where name like 'Microsoft Visual C++'"

(base) PS C:\Users\tzcbz> Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Product where name like 'Microsoft Visual C++%'"


IdentifyingNumber : {1D8E6291-B0D5-35EC-8441-6616F567A0F7}
Name              : Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219
Vendor            : Microsoft Corporation
Version           : 10.0.40219
Caption           : Microsoft Visual C++ 2010  x64 Redistributable - 10.0.40219

Update: In response to your further questions
Hi,
In response to your concern, I've successfully tested the updated code on my system which runs Windows 11 Insider and uses PowerShell version 5.1.22621.2706. The code performs as expected and yields the correct results.
However, when I ran it on an older computer equipped with Windows 7 and a PowerShell version dating back to before 2009, it encountered errors resulting in unpredictable behavior. The issue stems from the fact that the conditional check in the if-statement does not function correctly on earlier PowerShell versions.
To address this, I've made an amendment to line 5 of the code. Following this modification, the updated script should operate smoothly across all platforms, including the older Powershell versions.
$MSRedistributable = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Product where name like 'Microsoft Visual C++%'"
$MSRedistributableInstaller = "C:\Software"

Write-host "`nStaring Installation of Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022"
if (($null -eq $MSRedistributable) -or (!$MSRedistributable.PSObject.Properties.Match("name")))
{
Write-host "Installing Microsoft Visual C++."
Start-Process -Filepath "$($MSRedistributableInstaller)\VC_redist_2015-2022x64" -Argumentlist "/Q" -wait
Start-Process -Filepath "$($MSRedistributableInstaller)\VC_redist_2015-2022x86" -Argumentlist "/Q" -wait
write-host "Microsoft Visual C++ installed successfully."
}
else
{
write-host "$($MSRedistributable.name) appears to be installed already.  Skipping."
}


Hi Expert,
Thanks for your explanation. Your name logic 'like' its great. Its starting installing if I am using 'like'.  But only my concern is its not moving to else loop even though the Microsoft Visual C++ is already installed. Could you please help me on that part

@jimmyafflick I have revised my previous response to incorporate answers to your subsequent questions. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Your logic is working like a charm. Thanks much for the help. Means a lot.

I have marked your answer as right answer. You are great expert.
